# ReflectionException error on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, composer, mailchimp

I tried to install MailChimp module for Magento 2.

After I put all the files in the app/code/[vendor]/[module] and I run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, I received this error:

```
  [ReflectionException]
  Class Mailchimp does not exist
```

I tried with several version and for all of them, I received the same thing.

I got the extension from https://marketplace.magento.com/. So I think this should work fine.

Does anyone know how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that this module need a special library. If we take a look into the `composer.json` file located in the module files we can find that he required this library :

```
 "require" : {
    "ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib": "3.0.*"
  }
```

So in my case the only solution was to install this library via composer and then install the module also via composer.

To install via composer you need to run :

```
composer require ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib
```

`composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2`

If this will not work try to do the same thing in magento composer. and then run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

i hope this will help!

Comment: Hi, I followed these instructions and previous to installing the Mailchimp extension, I had their magemonkey extension installed.  AFter requiring the lib, I got the below error and now I can't access my admin panel!

Comment: Package ebizmarts/magento2-magemonkey's source key should be specified as {"type": ..., "url": ..., "reference": ...},
{"type":"git","url":"https:\/\/github.com\/ebizmarts\/magento2-magemonkey.git","reference":null} given.

Comment: While executing the "composer require ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib" removed the some extension(Mirasvit Followup email)  and  website through the error.

Answer (score 2):

After about 9 hours of reading through the internet and trying to find a solution, I ended up deleting the contents of my Vendor folder (but NOT .htaccess file) and running composer update command

`composer update`

This took away the error and I was able to delete the Magemonkey files and redownload the Ebizmarts library file:

```
composer require ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib
```

And then enable the Mailchimp extension.  THis was the biggest pain in the ass so I hope this helps someone in the future.

Just a note, after doing all this and running the upgrade and compile, you may need to reset permissions on your magento install, as I had to.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed same issue with composer command.

```
composer require ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib
```

You can also download zip folder of library.

https://api.github.com/repos/ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib/zipball/293960203ff1d834af5b2f2726f03063494a2265